# Использование clang (парсинг параметров функции)

Tags: c++, python, парсер, clang

У меня есть вопрос относительно этого замечательного инструмента.
Всем, кто с ним знаком, известно, что он является замечательным парсером языка C++ и его можно использовать для анализа кода.

И мне как раз понадобилось это сделать. Если быть конкретнее, мне необходимо получить список параметров из метода класса в виде: "Название парамера": "Тип параметра".

Проект очень большой. Это разработка на движке Unreal Engine 4. Поэтому проект имеет бешеное разнообразие типов, макросов и прочих необычных директив компилятора. Более того, огромное количества хедеров.

В общем проблема в том, что я не могу анализировать проект целиком, но анализировать конкретные хедеры, которые принадлежат мне, мне необходимо.

В данном случае я использую питоновскую обёртку Clang'а и просто загружаю файлы листинга с помощью clang.cindex.Index и index.parse.

В итоге я получаю дерево пространств имён. Классов, различных подсущностей и т д... И вроде могу просто уже спокойно это дерево разбирать... Однако... Если происходит какая либо ошибка (не найден инклуд или что-то ещё), то типы данных, которые в результате этой ошибки не были отпарсены ранее, превращаются в тип "**int**". И это очень печально. В результате выходит, что использованный по нанзначению инструмент не работает с такими правилами.
Однако, я думаю здесь есть специалисты, которые укажут на то, что я делаю не так.

В общем то цель моя просто спарсить аргументы, мне не нужно для этого подключать инклуды (если всё это дело подключать, это превратится в длительную операцию, и, вообще этот номер не пройдёт, так как нужно знать какие дейфайны нужны для всего проекта целиком). 
Что здесь можно сделать? Или не использовать Clang вовсе и какие-то другие решения здесь более приемлемы?

Пример кода, который нужно анализировать:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "UMG.h"
#include "Components/Overlay.h"
#include "MinimapMark.h"
#include "GUI/GUIBase.h"
#include "Tools.h"
#include "Minimap.generated.h"


USTRUCT(BlueprintType, Blueprintable)
struct FMinimapEntityEntry
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    UPROPERTY()
    AActor * Actor;

    UPROPERTY()
    UMinimapMark * Mark;

    UPROPERTY()
    UOverlaySlot * Slot;
};


UCLASS(Abstract)
class PROJECT_API UMinimap : public UGUIBase
{
    GENERATED_BODY()


public:
    UMinimap(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);
    virtual TSharedRef<SWidget> RebuildWidget() override;
    virtual void NativeTick(const FGeometry& MyGeometry, float InDeltaTime);

// Exposed functions
    ReceiverMethod(SetMarksData)
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent, BlueprintCallable, Category = Minimap)
    void UpdateMarks(const TArray<AActor*>& Actors, AActor* Player);
    virtual void UpdateMarks_Implementation(const TArray<AActor*>& Actors, AActor* Player);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = Minimap)
    void AddActor(AActor* Actor);

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = Minimap)
    void RemoveActor(AActor* Actor);


// Exposed fields
    TArray<AActor*> MapActors;
    FMinimapEntityEntry PlayerMark;
    TArray<FMinimapEntityEntry> Marks;


private:  // local widget pointers
    TWeakObjectPtr<UImage> Image;
    TWeakObjectPtr<UOverlay> Overlay;

    FRotator GetRotation();

};
```

Нужно извлечь параметры из функции UpdateMarks (типы и имена аргументов).

UFUNCTION и ReceiverMethod - это просто макросы.

Comment: @Abyx макрос вполне может быть определен в подключаемых заголовочных файлах.

Comment: @Abyx почему не подключает? А список из 6 `#include` это что?

Comment: @Abyx не понимаю, как это связано с Вашим первым комментарием. Вы же про валидность кода говорили.

Answer (score 2):

> В общем то цель моя просто спарсить аргументы, мне не нужно для этого подключать инклуды

В этом ваша ошибка. Чтобы просто распознать агрументы (синтаксический/семантический анализ -- [7 стадия компиляции](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases)), необходимо чтобы препроцессор успешно завершился (прошла [4 стадия компиляции](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases)). Другими словами, если отсутствуют заголовки с макросами, то файлы, которые у вас есть -- это просто каша макросов и фрагментов C++ кода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако я не могу подключать ВСЕ заголовки.
В принципе я могу подключить все макросы (что я и делал в данном случае, забыл оговорить). Но вот все типы данных я не могу через include всего проекта подключить. Слишком много зависимостей. Это просто будет означать ОЧЕНЬ длительную операцию. А эта операция должна будет выполняться довольно часто. Перед каждой новой компиляцией проекта.

Что же делать то в таком случае? Clang ведь тем не менее как то умудряется спарсить названия функции. Или другие методы? Может режимы инструмента?